# Inner product of imaginary vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I'm blanking on how to do the inner product of imaginary vectors. Would the imaginary part just become negative? Also how do we show those inequalities hold. This second part is the main problem I have.

Comment: The inner product is calculated the same way as for vectors from $\mathbb{R}^4$, just remembering how to multiply and add complex numbers.  For a reminder, see the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Addition_and_subtraction).

Comment: I have seen that you have asked a lot of questions recently, many with good answers. Is there any specific reason you dont accept the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Read the book before this point.  My guess: the inner product is defined with a conjugate in there, so
$$
\langle u,  v\rangle =(1)\overline{(1+i)}+(i)\overline{(2+3i)}+(1+i)\overline{(4+5i)}+(0)\overline{(6+7i)}
$$
This way, we always get $\langle x, x \rangle \ge 0$, so taking its square-root is a sensible way to compute the norm.

But if it is a physics book, the conjugate will be on the first factor instead of the second factor.

Comment: Do you know how the inequalities would be shown? That was my main question.

Comment: Compute those four numbers.  Then you have some inequalities involving them to prove.  What are those inequalities that you are supposed to prove?  Why are they difficult?

Answer (score 0):

For the inner product, would you not just do it as you normally would? Ie,

\begin{equation*}
u\cdot v=(1)(1+i)+(i)(2+3i)+(1+i)(4+5i)+(0)(6+7i)\\
\end{equation*}

and expand watching out for the complex multiplication and double brackets (ie, $xy=(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)$ for complex numbers $x=a+ib$ and $y=c+id,~i^2=-1$)?

For the second part, why not try substituting the vectors into the equations and see what you get? Ie, into

\begin{equation*}
||u+v||\leq ||u||+||v||,\\
|\langle u,v \rangle|\leq ||u||~||v||.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

$\langle v , w \rangle= \langle (1,i,1+i,0),(1+i,2+3i,4+5i,6+7i)\rangle$

the only thing we really need to recall here is that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ that is $i^2=-1$

$\langle v , w \rangle =(1)(1+i)+(i)(2+3i)+(1+i)(4+5i)+(0)(6+7i)$

$=1+i+2i+3i^2+4+5i^2$

$=5+3i-3-5$

$=3i-3$

$||v||=\sqrt{1+i^2+(1+i)^2}$

and $||w||= \sqrt{(1+i)^2+(2+3i)^2+(4+5i)^2+(6+7i)^2}$

to verify the inequalities, just use the definitions

Comment: The inequalities are not true. Consider $v=(1,i,0,0),\;w=(1,-i,0,0)$: $$\lVert v\rVert^2=\lVert w\rVert^2=1^2+i^2=0$$ $$\langle v,w\rangle=1\cdot1+i\cdot(-i)=2\not\leq0$$ The problem is that we were supposed to use the complex conjugate.